# pure javascript filter checkbox per column

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to create table where I can filter my data using a checkbox per column

by create function a and function b for check filter column

**Problem** : I want to check column to filter table contents on clean code and easy to use
(btw I don't understand how to use arrow functions)

have any way edit for my clean code ?

```js
const a = function filter(event) {
  var element = event.target
  var condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("check1")
  for (var i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = ""
      } else {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}

const b = function filter(event) {
  var element = event.target
  var condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("check2")
  for (var j = 0; j < condt1.length; j++) {
    if (condt1[j].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[j].parentElement.style = ""
      } else {
        condt1[j].parentElement.style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.option1')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', a));
  
  
document.querySelectorAll('.option2')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', b));
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <label>Filter Name </label><br>
  <label>Human<input class="option1" type="checkbox" value="Human" checked/></label>
  <label>Robot<input class="option1" type="checkbox" value="Robot"checked/></label><br><br>

  <label>Filter boolean </label><br>
  <label>true<input class="option2" type="checkbox" value="true" checked/></label>
  <label>false<input class="option2" type="checkbox" value="false" checked/></label>
</div>
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> boolean </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="check1">Human</td>
      <td class="check2">true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="check1">Robot</td>
      <td class="check2">false</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="check1">Human</td>
      <td class="check2">true</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="check1">false</td>
      <td class="check2">true</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sorry for my bad English, can't explain all what I need, hope you understand what I need

Thanks !

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Also, the `Name` of `false` looks like a typo

Comment: I want to short code for check column to filter (example) : if I want to add from 2 column to 3 column I need to create function c same function b and function a That to multiple duplicate code , Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single function rather than creating separate functions as most of your logic is common across the functions.

```
function filter(event, filterCol) {
  let element = event.target;
  let condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName(filterCol);
  for (let i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = ""
      } else {
        condt1[i].parentElement.style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.option1')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', ()=>filter(event,"check1")));
  
  
document.querySelectorAll('.option2')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', ()=>filter(event,"check2")));
```

Thanks.